# iphone keyboard loop due to JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

I'm using a code snippet that I found on codepen:

https://codepen.io/559wade/pen/LRzEjj

basically, it automatically formats a field with commas and decimals after you've typed in a number if you have the data-type of "currency".

```
<input type="text" name="currency-field" id="currency-field" pattern="^\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$" value="" data-type="currency" placeholder="$1,000,000.00">
```

like so.

Now this works fine, however there's a bug when I try to use this on my phone (I'm not sure if this is an issue exclusive to mobile or iPhones), that makes it so that once I focus onto this field, it brings up the keyboard, but no matter how many times I hit the "Done" button or click away, the keyboard goes away then immediately comes back. I've replicated this bug on both iPhone 5 and 6.

[image]

I'm not sure which part of the JS could be causing this.